# MediaElement Redirect AudioOutput to Speaker

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone, mediaelement

I am implementing VOIP Application, and i have to configure Output device, and switch between AudioOutput device should be provided,
Means

-- As in Normal Phone,there is provision to switch between Headset and Speaker,

Is there way i can achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in WP7, its supported in WP8, only thing is we have to use WASAPI framework.